# GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY DB2

Tags: database, db2

I m using DB2 and when i created my table i used `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` for the primary key.
When i insert a new row on the tables, the generated value of the primary key is not the max of IDs.

Is that normal ?

The number generated is not duplicated but it is not the maximum.

Comment: Do you mean the max of already inserted IDs? And were those existing IDs generated?

Comment: Yes, If i have on the tables IDs (7, 9,10), when i insert a new row, i get on ID 8 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior is expected. See the [CREATE TABLE statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-table) and the options for AS IDENTITY. You can set a start value (START WITH) to tell Db2 to count from a specific value onwards.

The algorithm which database systems use for identity columns is to have a sequence. They obtain values from that sequence. They don't actively look for available values within the existing data.